# Book recommendation/reference request on regular (abstract) polytopes

Tags: reference-request, polytopes

My actual goal is understanding highly symmetric polytopes. For example, regular polytopes, archimedean solids, complex regular polytopes, regular abstract polytopes, etc.

I apologize that I don't know the general term including all of these concepts hence I use the term regular abstract polytopes.

I choose **H.S.M. Coxeter, Regular Polytopes** and **Peter McMullen, Egon Schulte, Abstract Regular Polytopes** to refer.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The two books you mention, Coxeter and McMullen & Schulte, are the standard texts on the subject. You can also add Coxeter's *Regular Complex Polytopes*.

However polytopes and high symmetries are distinct areas of study which do not overlap as cleanly as one might expect. For example a regular complex polytope has no bounding surface in the topological sense but is better understood as a configuration. An abstract polytope is a class of incidence complex having a "diamond condition" ensuring for example that faces meet in pairs along edges and so on, but each cell (subface of 3 or more dimensions) does not need to be a topological ball. These both fly in the face of the simplicial decomposition of a manifold in order to determine its homology class, which is derived from Euler's original polyhedron formula V − E + F = 2 and leads to the understanding of a polytope as a class of topological CW complex.

A simple and well-illustrated introduction to the symmetry aspect is provided by Conway, Burgiel and Goodman-Strauss in *The Symmetries of Things*, while a good account of the topological origins is given by David S. Richeson in *Euler's Gem: The Polyhedron Formula and the Birth of Topology*.

You can find my own embryonic attempt at resolving some of these inconsistencies at http://www.steelpillow.com/polyhedra/morphic/morphic.html

Comment: I agree that my attention is closer to your suggestion. Very intriguing!

Answer (score 1):

Two standard references:

- [Lectures on Polytopes](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387943299) by Ziegler.
- [Convex Polytopes](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387004242) by Grünbaum.

Comment: Definitely a good start for studying polytopes in general. Not much of a source for symmetric polytopes though. But everybody needs these basics to think about the latter.